# cv.glmnet and Leave-one-out CV + Warning

Tags: r, glmnet, loocv

I'm using `cv.glmnet` with Leave-One-Out Cross-Validation (LOOCV), but I'm getting the following warning message:

**Warning message:
Option grouped=FALSE enforced in cv.glmnet, since < 3 observations per fold**

Even though I'm using LOOCV, I still encounter this error. My dataset is defined as follows, and there are no missing values:

[image: screenshot of values]

In the situation described above, is it safe to ignore such warning messages?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for the community to help you better, please provide your dataset in the form of a code (not as an image) and provide the `cv.glmnet()` command that you used. [Click here to see suggestions on how to provide you dataset in the form of a code.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) For example, you can use `dput(X)` to write the code of your dataset `X`.